# Updating state of parent component sets child state to default values

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with collapsible rows, and I have two components for them, the parent is the `Table` the child is each `CollapsibleRow`.

The table tracks the state of `items` in useEffect, and updates whenever something changes.

Each row also has its own state to track if its collapsed or not, default is collapsed (in my case `false`).

Whenever the state of the `Table` changes, the collapsed state, gets set back to `false` (i.e. if a row was "opened" when the state change occurs, it gets closed, because its state gets set back to default closed state).

```
export default function Table() {
  const { stock } = useContext(stockContext);

  return (<Table>
            {stock.map(stockItem => <TableCollapsibleRow key={uuidv4()} stockItem={stockItem}/>)}
         </Table>)
}
```

And the basics of the row:

```
export default function TableCollapsibleRow({ stockItem }) {
  const [stockItemOpen, setStockItemOpen] = useState(false);

  const openCloseOnClickHandler = () => {
    setStockItemOpen(prevState => !prevState);
  }

  return <Collapse onClick={openCloseOnClickHandler} in={stockItemOpen}><TableRow>.....</TableRow></Collapse>
}
```

So if `stockItemOpen` is `true` (the row is not collapsed and the additional stuff can be viewed), and `stock` changes while it is `true`, its set back to the default `false` and it gets collapsed.

I have tried to make an arbitrary `stuff` variable, to see if it the behavior is somehow related to the implementation of the table:

```
  const [stuff, setStuff] = useState(false);

  const openCloseOnClickHandler = () => {
    setStuff(true);
    setStockItemOpen((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  console.log(`${stuff} stuff`);
```

It too gets set back to false, whenever state gets updated.

As far as the context of stock goes:

```
  const [stock, setStock] = useState([]);

  const addToStockOperation = (data) => {
    ..do some stuff with the data..

    setStock(prevStock => ...code that sets new stock...)
  }
```

And this `addToStockOperation` method is used by a button within the `TableCollapsibleRow` component.

Comment: Can you share an example of what your context looks like?

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you never assign the `key` prop. Have a look into your console, to see if you're missing them somewhere. See [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: @foxxycodes I added a bit of information about the context, as far as the key goes, I have updated the post, I do have keys, I just forgot to type them in the code here, as I am not copy/pasting the code, but manually typing it to keep it clear of fluff that doesnt relate to the problem.

Comment: @foxxycodes it is the key, I was using uuidv4 which as `dbuchet` said is generating new key everytime, so thats why its happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a unique `key` in your map

```js
{
 stock.map(stockItem => <TableCollapsibleRow key={stockItem.id} stockItem={stockItem}/>)
}
```

This way, React can keep tracks of children, and keep their inner states

-- UPDATE --

I see you've udapted for `uuidv4` in key. So at each render, you're generating a new `key`. So for React, it's a new component! You have to keep same ids at each render (that's why I was suggesting `stockItem.id`)

Comment: My fault for missing to include that, but I do have keys in the map.

Comment: I see you've udapted for `uuidv4` in key. So at each render, you're generating a new `key`. So for React, it's a new component! You have to keep same ids at each render (that's why I was suggesting `stockItem.id`)

Comment: HOLY SMOKES! I didnt realize that, I changed it to use the id from the db (as you suggested) and now it works. Add it to your answer, I'm accepting it.

Comment: Glad it fixed your issue :)